# Split arrays in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, join

I want to split arrays in an array and get the string of the second elements mixed.

```
[["c","a","t"], ["d","o","g"]]
...
# => "ao"
```

How can I do it? I tried the `join` method and got the second and the fifth ones. But when the word length is different like this:

```
[["b","i","r","d"], ["c","a","t"]]
```

I don't know how to do it. Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> ary = [["c","a","t"], ["d","o","g"]]
=> [["c", "a", "t"], ["d", "o", "g"]]
> ary.map{|a| a[1]}.join
=> "ao"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this :

```
> [["c","a","t"], ["d","o","g"]].collect{|e| e[1]}.join
=> "ao"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help

```
a = [["b","i","r","d"], ["c","a","t"]]
result = a.collect{ |_,s,*__| s }.join
p result 
# => "ia"
```